# Q-Learning in combination with neural-networks (rewarding understanding)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, neural-network

As far as my understanding is, it's possible to replace a look-up-table for Q-values (state-action-pair-evaluation) by a neural network for estimating these state-action pairs. I programmed a small library, which is able to propagate and backpropagate through a self-built neural network for learning wanted target-values for a certain in-out-put.

So I also found this site while googling, and googling through the whole web (as it felt for me): http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~gasser/Salsa/nn.html where the Q-learning combined with a neural network is shortly explained.

For each action, there's an extra output neuron, and the activation-value of one of these output-"units" tells me, the estimated Q-value. (One question: Is the activation value the same as the "output" of the neuron or something different?)

I used the standard sigmoid-function as activation-function, so the range of the function-values x is

```
0<x<1
```

So I thought, my target value should always be from 0.0 to 1.0 -> Question: Is that point of my understanding correct? Or did I missunderstand something about that?

If yes, there comes following problem:
The equation for calculating the target-reward / new Q-value is:
q(s,a) = q(s,a) + learningrate * (reward + discountfactor * q'(s,a) - q(s,a))

So how do I perform this equation to get the right target for the neural network, if targets should be from 0.0 to 1.0?!
How do I calculate good reward-values? Is moving toward the aim more worth it, than going away from it? (more +reward when nearing the aim than -reward for bigger distance to aim?)

I think there are some missunderstandings of mine. I hope, you can help me to answer that questions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Using a neural-network to store q-value is a good extension of table lookup. This makes it possible to use q-learning when the state space is continuous.

```
  input layer     ......  

                |/  \ |  \|
  output layer  a1   a2   a3
                0.1  0.2  0.9
```

Suppose you have 3 actions available. Above shows the outputs from the neural network using current state and learned weights. So you know `a3` is the best action to go with.

Now the questions you have:

> One question: Is the activation value the same as the "output" of the neuron or something different?

Yes, I think so. In the referred link, the author said:

> Some of the units may also be designated output units; their activations represent the network's response.

---

> So I thought, my target value should always be from 0.0 to 1.0 -> Question: Is that point of my understanding correct? Or did I missunderstand something about that?

If you choose `sigmoid` as your activation function, for sure you output will be from 0.0 to 1.0. There are different choices of activation functions, e.g., [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Artificial_Neural_Networks/Activation_Functions). `Sigmoid` is one of the most popular choices though. I think the output value being from 0.0 to 1.0 is not a problem here. if at current time, you have only two available actions, `Q(s,a1) = 0.1, Q(s,a2) = 0.9`, you know that action `a2` is much better than `a1` with respective to q-value.

---

> So how do I perform this equation to get the right target for the neural network, if targets should be from 0.0 to 1.0?! How do I calculate good reward-values?

I am not sure for this, but you can try to clamp the new target q-value to be between 0.0 and 1.0, i.e.,

```
q(s,a) = min(max(0.0, q(s,a) + learningrate * (reward + discountfactor * q'(s,a) - q(s,a))), 1.0)
```

Try to do some experiments for finding a proper reward value.

---

> Is moving toward the aim more worth it, than going away from it? (more +reward when nearing the aim than -reward for bigger distance to aim?)

Normally you should give more reward when it's close to the aim if you use the classical update equation, so that the new q-value gets increased.

Comment: wow thank you for that detailed answer! I just got another question about that: Is it quite useful to clamp the new target, or is there a chance of "wrong" behaviour of my agent?

Comment: I am not sure. Unless you post some results here. Are you doing the epsilon-exploration for the agent? check the post here also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148934/unbounded-increase-in-q-value-consequence-of-recurrent-reward-after-repeating-t/13153633#13153633

Comment: Jup, the first thing I wanted to do is an "arrow", which should have the mission to find a red point (food or something). But even this easy-seeming task is not very easy for me :(

Comment: How about first implementing a table-lookup version of q-learning for your red-point mission (suppose you have discrete state space, check the link to the source code in my previous comment). Then try the neural network q-value storage for the same problem.

Comment: That would not be my intention generally. I see what you mean by this, but in first case this would not be what I am trying to do. In first case it's not about learning via Q-Learning, in my case I want to understand the use of a neural network. I found one more paper, where linear-function is proposed for the output layer. That would probably allow me to get a better range for the target values. Is that a good idea? http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb/INC/l7.pdf

Comment: Yeah, linear activation at the output layer is good for regression problems. So it's a good choice to try for your case.

Comment: There's one last question I've got before giving you the "accepted" ;) Maybe you know the answer. I read some articles about the linear output-thing and one of them mentioned that the deverative of any linear function is constant, which it is obvious. But as I started to use the deverative and linear function for the last layer my whole network didn't work anymore... and I noticed, that I don't really know how to do the back-propagation with sigmoid for hidden + linear for output layer.

Comment: 0. please elaborate on `my whole network didn't work`. what is the behavior before and after? 1. check your back-propagation formula, a good graphical illustration is here: http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html. make sure you calculate `delta` correctly. 2. start with a small learning rate. 3. try momentum terms. 4. Try to post your core code or a link here.

Comment: okay, I didn't clean up my code yet, because of all the testing... Should I just upload the code for construction and calculations on the neural network itself or also the scenario for Q-learning?

Comment: btw, what I meant by "it didn't work anymore" were kind of things like connection-weights got NAN or negative huge numbers. Things like converging values, instead of diverging.